# is there something similar to target_include_files in cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

Is there any way to add files in the same manner as target include directories but for individual files?

My use case is this. I'm using a lot of templates and concepts and my header files are getting bulky. I really liked having implementation split from definitions so want something like so:

### .h file

```cpp
template <typename T>
T foo(T bar);

#include <name_of_implementation_file>
```

### implementation .h file

```cpp
template <typename T>
T foo(T bar) { return bar; };
```

currently the include has to look like so: `#include "path/to/implementation_file_name"`

This is annoying as it makes refactoring a pain later. I also don't want to add extra directories with just 1 or 2 files and call `target_include_directories`. I don't want to just `include` as my project is a library and I don't want the user to be able to include the implementation files. I am also building multiple targets and want to keep their included files separate.

Comment: Well for starters, you shouldn't `#include` a `cpp` file.

Comment: For templates, don't you need the **full** definition in the header file itself? You can keep the .cpp file, but it would largely be empty.

Comment: @0x5453 sure, so let's say the implementation file is another header

Comment: @squareskittles I include the implmentation at the bottom of the header file so it is still complete and will compile + link

Comment: Create a directory. Copy the file to that directory. Add that directory to include paths. | Anyway, just keep implementation in the same directory as the header and include the filename. `and I don't want the user to be able to include the implementation files` Are you instantiating the template in your source files? Most probably not, that makes it impossible - for the user to use the template, he has to see the implementation...

Comment: @KamilCuk If I have a directory with implementation (as shown in q, i don't instantiate but I write the function body in terms of a type T) and the header which I want the user to include and call target include directories then that target includes everything at PUBLIC and the user can include the implementation file. Also, I end up with extra directories. I'd like to just be able to add a line in the CmakeLists which is in the same directory as the implementation file

Comment: Do you [instantiate the template for specific set of types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template#Explicit_instantiation) in your source files or do you want users of your library to instantiate the template for any types themselves?

Comment: @KamilCuk I'd like the user to be able to do that themselves, in my library I have a collection of base classes I expect them to inherit from and then pass to my types hence just putting something like foo<int> at the top of my .cpp file will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: for user to use a template, user has to see it *all*.

> is there something similar to target_include_files in cmake

No, there is not.

> Is there any way to add files in the same manner as target include directories but for individual files?

The only way is:

- create an empty directory (somewhere within `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR`)
- copy the file there
- add that directory to include_directories

Just for fun, that looks easy to implement, in untested pseudocode:

```
function(target_include_files target mode)
    string(MD5 dir "${ARGN}")
    set(dir ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${dir})
    file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${dir})
    foreach(i IN LISTS ARGN)
       # TODO: replace with build-time generation
        configure_file(${i} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${dir} COPYONLY)
    endforeach()
    target_include_directories(${target} ${mode} ${dir})
endfunction()
```

> I really liked having implementation split from definitions so want something like so:

The simplest would be to keep implementation files in the same directory as header files - that way, simple `#include "file"` would suffice, because includes with `"` search current include directory first. If not - move implementation files to a subdirectory, and just include the subdirectory also relative to current file. If not - add the other directory with implementation files to search paths.

> I don't want the user to be able to include the implementation files.

So, as some closed source C++ libraries do, explicitly instantiate the template for common types in source files and provide external explicit instantiations declarations in your header files for the types they were templated for. This would of cause limit the usability of your templates to only the types you explicitly instantiated for.

> I'd like the user to be able to do that [instantiate the template] themselves,

Then it's *impossible* to do it (or it makes your library just unusable and pointless). Anyone who uses the template, to instantiate it *has to* see the *whole definition* of the template (or, in some cases, an external explicit instantiation for that type can be provided in a separate translation unit, mentioned above). If the user will not see the whole definitions of all symbols he uses and an external explicit instantiation will not be provided, the user will just end up with `undefined reference to` symbols from the template.

For further research, I advise to just research the term "explicit instantiation" in the context of C++, templates and when it's used and how does it differ from "implicit instantiation". For more further research, review materials about how compiler and linker work, what is *linkage* and how C++ templates were designed.